# Adding ip address via request.ip to devise's forgotten password mail view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, ip-address

I'd like add an ip address to devise forgotten passwords email using `request.remote_ip`. I can't use devise's ip attributes since the user has not logged in.

Where do I check the `request.ip`? I can't access devise's controller and place the code there, and I can't put it in the views

how should it best be done? Must I rewrite all devises actions just for one small request.ip call?

Comment: Is there any way to do this. I am also facing the same issue.